# how do i install Drupal commerce module? i have installed composer

Tags: drupal, composer-php

I need to install the commerce module via composer, how can I do that? I dont know how to install it, I did it manually but unsuccessfully

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well, i installled composer, now I need to install a module, the commerce module

Comment: Run `composer require drupal/commerce`

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package drupal/commerce.

  Did you mean this?
      drupal/commerce_taxcloud
I think I have to install the project-base first. But it says "mystore" what is the path to install?

Comment: You've said that you tried to install the commerce module. How did you do that? What does "unsuccessfully" mean? Is there any error message given?